# Linearization of bilinear terms

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to linearize the product of two continuous variables for an optimization problem.

I have tried McCormick relaxation and piece-wise McCormick relaxation, but those relaxation are not tight enough for my problem.

Does anyone know any good trick to linearize the bilinear terms? The method that requires the least number of binary variables would be great.

Thank you,

Comment: I think frank talk is in order. There is a reason why the McCormick relaxation is referred to by its developer's name: it is one of the best known approaches in the literature. Most others simply add heuristic adjustments to it, and their performance is highly model-dependent. There is no good reason to believe that a StackExchange post is going to yield better options than a solid literature search.

Comment: Thank you for you comment.

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck.  If both variables are continuous, their product can not be linearized.  Face the music, you have a nonlinear model. If relaxations are not good enough for you, you'll need a nonlinear solver.

If one of the variables were binary, you could use big-M modeling.  But that doesn't apply in your case.

Comment: Hello Mark, Thank you for your answer. Actually, I tried one reformulation that utilizes the following identity: ab = ((a+b)/2)^2 - ((a-b)/2))^2. Afterwards, the quadratic terms are piecewise-linearized. The results are accurate to great extent, but the major problem with this formulation is the involvement of large number of binary variables in piecewise linearization method for large cases. This renders the problem computationally difficult to solve. I was wondering if there is any way to reduce the binary variables in piecewise linearization method.

Comment: Of course, you exchanged one non-convex quadratic for another, and then you only approximately solved that. I recommend you use a nonlinear optimization solver. You haven't shown the entirety of your problem, so i can't recommend a specific type of nonlinear solver. If the only nonlinearlity is in the objective function, you can use a Quadratic Programming (QP) solver able to handle non-convex objectives. If the nonlinearity is in the constraints, you will need a solver which can handle nonlinear constraints. And you haven't said whether you have any (other) integer or binary variables.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [enter link description here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/aic.12109/full). This article introduces 10 methods for your problem.